# Copying columns of values from Excel worksheet to an HTML table in a website

Tags: html, vba, excel, macros

I'm hoping to copy values from an excel table  into an html table. If anyone has experience doing this between Excel 2013 and Internet Explorer 11, please let me know and I can give details. Thank you

The following is a little section of the code for the website that I am trying to automate the fill-in process for:

[Table and Source Code for Charge Numbers for the Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6WaM.png)

This is showing just one part of the process (the charge numbers), which we have anywhere from 10-25 each week with their corresponding hours charged to them each day (as seen in the table matrix).

There are 7 charge numbers on each page and Charge Numbers all have **name="chargeNo"** and increase id names with each box downward like so:

```
'1) id="chargeNo0"  
'2) id="chargeNo1"  
'3) id="chargeNo2"  
'4) id="chargeNo3"  
'5) id="chargeNo4"  
'6) id="chargeNo5"  
'7) id="chargeNo6"
```

**Each day of the week also has set names as follows:**

[Table and Source Code for Hours Charged Each Day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EZyQ.png)

```
'Saturday: name="hrs0"  
'Sunday: name="hrs1"  
'Monday: name="hrs2"  
'Tuesday: name="hrs3"  
'Wed: name="hrs4"  
'Thurs: name="hrs5"  
'Fri: name="hrs6"
```

I'm trying to automate the process of pulling the arrays of charge times I have from Excel and inputting them into their respective textboxes.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And include the code you are trying to work through...so people can help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert a range to an html table so it can become all or part of a web page?  Does the web site have a form which you wish to fill in using VBA? These are just two possible meanings of your question. Had you included your faulty code we could have guessed what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This script will convert elements in ColumnA into an array.

```
Sub MakeArray()
   Dim arr As Variant

   With ActiveSheet
      arr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range(.[A1], .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))
   End With
End Sub


Sub MakeString()
   Dim s As String

   Const DELIMITER = ","

   With ActiveSheet
      s = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range(.[A1], .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))), DELIMITER)
   End With
End Sub
```

If you want to pass the array to an HTML TextBox, try this.

```
    Sub CreateArrayAndPassToHTMLTextbox()
       Dim ie  As Object
       Dim arr As Variant

       Const DELIMITER = ","

       Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

       ie.Visible = True
       ie.navigate "http://home.arcor.de/peter.schleif/SearchForTDelement.html"
       While ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

       With ActiveSheet
          arr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range(.[A1], .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))
          If Not IsArray(arr) Then arr = Array(arr)
          ie.document.getElementById("trackField").Value = Join(arr, DELIMITER)
       End With
    End Sub
```

If, for instance, you want to pass data to a ComboBox, try this.

```
Sub passValueToComboBox1()
   Dim ie  As Object
   Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement

   Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   ie.Visible = True
   ie.navigate "http://peterschleif.bplaced.net/excel/combobox/index.php"
   While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

   Set oHTML_Element = ie.document.getElementsByName("selectedReportClass")(0)
   If Not oHTML_Element Is Nothing Then oHTML_Element.Value = "com.db.moap.report.FUBU7"

   For Each oHTML_Element In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
      If oHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
   Next
End Sub
```